# Proxies not working with requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm recently working on occasional data intensive projects and I'm in need of gathering data from e-commerce platforms like Amazon so I created a web scraping program in Python. I'm using requests library along with a list of user agents and proxies however I think they are not working and it is causing failure of the program. Note that Amazon Api is limiting in terms of content and access rates and is not suitable for my needs.

Here's how I send requests:

```
import requests
import random

session = requests.session()
proxies = [{'https:': 'https://' + item.rstrip(), 'http':
            'http://' + item.rstrip()} for item in open('proxies.txt').readlines()]
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) '
            'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}

print(session.get('https://icanhazip.com', proxies=random.choice(proxies), headers=user_agent).text)
```

However I keep getting the same ip address printed and this means the proxies are not working this way. and the proxies.txt contains proxies in this format:

ex:

`178.168.19.139:30736`

`342.552.34.456:8080`

`...`

What is the best way to workaround captchas and robot checks presented by Amazon using these tools (or extra tools if you have any suggestions) and why are the proxies failing to work?

Comment: I would assume that Amazon's captchas and robot checks don't have an easy workaround. Before continuing this path check if there is an API provided, for example, does Product Advertising API meets your needs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/WhatIsA2S.html)?

Comment: No it does not meet my needs

Comment: What type of captchas? How often do you get them? You can automate captcha solving by using third party services with real people solving them. And it's not expensive at all.

Comment: html content titled 'Robot Check' and temporary ip bans is what I'm getting mostly and with like 20 threads, you're getting 20 captchas per second so whatever the solution is, it must be dealing with these robot checks in the first place, if you want to take a look at the whole code let me know but I think it won't make any difference.

Comment: Did you try what I put below?

Comment: yeah, same issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but I found that removing the protocol at the start of the ip within the dictionary solved the problem.

```
proxies = [{'https': item.rstrip(), 'http': item.rstrip()} for item in open('proxies.txt').readlines()]
```